# MeteorJS: Get total count on App Startup of Collection

Tags: meteor

I have this code:

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
  Deps.autorun(function(){
    var j = Jobs.find().count();
    console.log(j);
  });
});
```

A couple of things.

A) The console prints 4 different times with 4 different results (incrementing the count up: (0, 164, 687, 2228))

B) How do you get Meteor to read the count only once?

Comment: Is this server or client, or both? Problems and possible solutions are kind of different depending on where you are.

Comment: This is on the client side

Comment: You can use your subscription's onready callback. And if you want it only once, you can use http://underscorejs.org/#once